Convert string to float from csv
In python, when I save as csv, my float 1.8967e-07 is a string now '[1.8967e-04]'. Note that every element now is a string, for example, '.' is a string, 'e' is a string, '-' is a string, I tried to use replace, but result in cannot convert '.' to float, I feel like replace here is not a optimal solution, could anybody help me please?
the result is expected to be 1.8967e-04 as float type

could anybody help me please? Without seeing your code, all we can say is "you made some mistake in saving the csv file".

@JohnGordon, yes you are correct, I didn't specify the type of my variables so that it was string as default when save as csv. Thanks!

By simply appending the data to the CSV file with the csv library, you can get it back as a float when reading it.  What is does is simply append it to the csv, and read it row by row, getting the type of the first element in each row, in this case, a float.
Here is the example code:
import csv

# Your data
data = [[1.8967e-07], [0.123], [4.567e-08]]

# Open a CSV file in 'w' mode with newline=''
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    # Create a CSV writer object
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    
    # Write each row to the CSV file
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)

with open('output.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in data:
        # This will print float, float, float
        print(type(row[0]))




The built-in float function will work just fine in your case.
num = '[1.8967e-04]'
num_float = float(num.replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))

